# caret: `predict` fails when `train` formula has deleted variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

**TL/DR ANSWER: specify training data in `newdata` argument.**

How do I consistently extract class probabilities from trained models with `caret`'s `predict`? Currently I get an error when the argument to `predict` was trained with the formula notation and a variable was indicated to be ignored with `-variable`.

This can be reproduced with:

```
fit.lda <- train(Species ~ . -Petal.Length, 
  data = iris, 
  preProcess = c("center", "scale"), 
  trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
    number = 10, 
    repeats = 3, 
    classProbs = TRUE, 
    savePredictions = "final", 
    selectionFunction = "best", 
    summaryFunction = multiClassSummary), 
  method = "lda", 
  metric = "Mean_F1")
```

and then the following line will fail:

```
predict(fit.lda, type = "prob")
```

> Error in predict.lda(modelFit, newdata) : wrong number of variables

If the `-Petal.Length` is omitted in the `train` formula, there is no error. Am I doing something wrong with the formula statement?

<s>I suppose I could dig into the model's `pred` slot and grab the columns corresponding to the class types (see EDIT2), but this seems hackish.</s> Is there a way to get `predict` to work as expected?

=====**EDIT**=====

I trained a number of different models (using formula notation) with `caretList` from the `caretEnsemble` package, and I got various errors when trying to use `predict`:

- `knn`

> Error in knn3Train(train = c(....) : dims of 'test' and 'train differ

- `svmRadial`:

> Warning message:
>   In method$prob(modelFit = modelFit, newdata = newdata, submodels = param) :
>     kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs

- `mlpML`:

> Error in myFunc[[1]](x, ...) : 
>     number of input data columns 28 does not match number of input neurons 20

Methods that worked without errors were `nnet` and tree based methods (`rf`, `xgbTree`)

=====**EDIT2**=====

The following doesn't take repeated resampling into account. The selected answer is much simpler.

<s>Here's a self-fashioned solution for extracting probabilities from the trained model, but for standardization, I'd prefer if it's possible to get `predict` to behave.</s>

```
grabProbs <- function(model) model$pred[, colnames(model$pred) %in% model$levels]

grabProbs(fit.lda)
```

Comment: what is your question now?

Comment: @sandipan I just want to use `predict` to have a standardized way of extracting class probabilities from a trained model (and also predicting on new data later)... exactly what `predict` is meant to be. Edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `newdata` parameter and it will work

```
predict(fit.lda, newdata = iris, type = "prob")
```

**[EDITED]**

As we can see, for `lda` the prediction result is identical:

```
library(MASS)
fit.lda <- lda(Species ~ . -Petal.Length, data = iris)
identical(predict(fit.lda), predict(fit.lda, newdata=iris))
# [1] TRUE

library(randomForest)
fit.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ . -Petal.Length, data = iris)
identical(predict(fit.rf), predict(fit.rf, newdata=iris))
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. This seems to work. I'm confused why it didn't work without specifying `newdata`. From `predict` documentation: "`newdata`: an optional set of data to predict on. If NULL, then the original training data are used"

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is correct: see Hong Ooi's post at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112052/130941 It seems `predict` might give different results depending on whether `newdata = train` is specified or not.

Comment: But the model we are using here is `lda` and not `rf`, so we don't have any `OOB` concepts. updated the above post, check it out.

Comment: I'm wary with `predict` behaving differently for different models. I used `lda` for the reproducible example, but for my actual problem I'm using `caretEnsemble` to train and predict many models including `rf`. So unless I check for identical results with and without `newdata` for each model, this is unfortunately not a complete solution.

Comment: What do you exactly want is not clear. (1) If you want prediction on the training dataset then the above with `newdata` will always work no matter what the model is. (2) if you want OOB estimates for RF like models (which is different from the prediction on the training dataset) you can already get that without using the `newdata` parameter, and it does work for RF like models, as you mentioned in your post and I also checked. So both ways it covers all the cases and is a complete solution I think.

Comment: I want class probability predictions by the model based on the training set. Looks like with `newdata`, `predict` always works. So, I'll re-accept the answer. :) Now I'm doubting the validity of ever using it without `newdata` when comparing different types of models. The fact remains that the original errors do not occur when the `train` formula does not contain deleted variables. So, it does seem like a bug in `predict`.